# Error from workflow to update a list when value in another list changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I created a workflow to update a list (`Rooms`) when another list (`People`) is changed. I want to assign a value in the `Room` column in `People` list and have the value in column `LastName` be added to the `Occupant` column in `Rooms`. I've tried several iterations, and keep getting an error that has no meaningful information (at least to me).

Here's my workflow:
[image]

Here's the `People` list settings:
[image]

Here's the `Room` list settings:
[image]

Here's the workflow error (Status: suspended):
[image]

Any idea what this error means or what I'm doing wrong? What value can't be null? Isn't that what I'm checking for in the first step? As a first-time Sharepoint user, I'm really discouraged by how difficult this simple task seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, but is the Room in the People list unique, i.e. are their multiple list entries in the people list that have the same room?  If so the workflow will not be able to use room in the people list as a unique identifier in the lookup, since there is more than one entree in the people list with the same room.

Comment: That seems logical, I hadn't seen that before. I just tried making both Room and RoomNumber unique, and now it has a slightly different error. At first it paused with this message: "Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP NotFound to https://..." Any idea what that refers to?

Comment: can you post the full error?

Answer (score 0):

In transition to stage, try to remove the condition and just go to the end of workflow. See if the error will still exist.

Comment: That's a good idea. I just tried that, unfortunately it looks like it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Does the item in Rooms list get updated? Try to terminate the workflow and restart it again.